# Appcache Enabled has depreciated

Tags: android, webview

I want that in my webview that whenever i visit any url every page should be stored in cache and it should be shown when internet is not provided this should be done with every url. And should be updated when these urls are opened again please help. I am creating a chatting application with django and wants webview to integrate with it.

My website- dinka.pythonanywhere.com

I want a code which should end this problem